# How to Export all schema objects for DB2 AS/400(iseries)?

Tags: database, windows-xp, db2, ibm-midrange

Hi i'm using windows xp and i have IBM system i navigator to connect to my AS/400 IBM DB2 database.I want to know how can i export all objects of my schema to my local PC(Win XP)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Databases > Schemas > your schema > All Objects

Right click, then Generate SQL.  This will make the SQL statements needed to re-create the objects in the schema.